# cfif isdate(URL.day) issue - always calling cfelse?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, coldfusion-8

We have the below code (partial code) that is used as part of a scheduling system where we can add and edit information for various classes. When we initiate the "copy from previous date" function, we get sent back "The date is invalid", which you'll note is part of a cfelse condition towards the bottom of the code (the initial cfif, I believe, is the first one below). This doesn't happen in all browsers, however; it works in some Windows versions of Firefox.

```
<cfif isdate(URL.day)>
    do a bunch of stuff...
```

...

```
    <cfoutput>  
    <p><strong>Copy Schedule from:</strong> <select name="scheduleCopy" size="1" onchange="parent.F7cms.content.iframe('scheduleManagerDay#URL.day#-tab1','components/custom/scheduleManager.cfm?day=#URL.day#&copy_day=' + this.value);"><option value="">-- SELECT DAY --</option><cfloop query="pastDays"><option value="#day_id#">#dateFormat(day_date,"DDDD, MMMM D, YYYY")#</option></cfloop></select></p>
    </cfoutput>
```

...

```
<cfelse>
    <cfoutput><h2>The date is invalid.</h2></cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

In essence, the cfelse, "the date is invalid", is being shown when the below function is being used. This function is used to copy information from one date to another, and we believe that the date is in fact perfectly valid. I think the offending cfif is . I've put much of the code in that I think is relevant to helping narrow down the issue. Any tips would be appreciated.

Also, the code that initiates the process that leads to "the date is invalid" is this:

```
<cfoutput>  
<p><strong>Copy Schedule from:</strong> <select name="scheduleCopy" size="1"       onchange="parent.F7cms.content.iframe('scheduleManagerDay#URL.day#-tab1','components/custom/scheduleManager.cfm?day=#URL.day#&copy_day=' + this.value);"><option value="">-- SELECT DAY --</option><cfloop query="pastDays"><option value="#day_id#">#dateFormat(day_date,"DDDD, MMMM D, YYYY")#</option></cfloop></select></p>
</cfoutput>
```

Here is the HTML generated from that above code, when clicked leading to error:

```
<p><strong>Copy Schedule from:</strong> <select name="scheduleCopy" size="1" onchange="parent.F7cms.content.iframe('scheduleManagerDay2011-09-5-tab1','components/custom/scheduleManager.cfm?day=2011-09-5&copy_day=' + this.value);"><option value="">-- SELECT DAY --</option><option value="266">Sunday, September 4, 2011</option><option value="265">Saturday, September 3, 2011</option><option value="264">Friday, September 2, 2011</option><option value="263">Thursday, September 1, 2011</option><option value="262">Wednesday, August 31, 2011</option><option value="261">Tuesday, August 30, 2011</option><option value="260">Monday, August 29, 2011</option><option value="259">Sunday, August 28, 2011</option><option value="258">Saturday, August 27, 2011</option><option value="257">Friday, August 26, 2011</option><option value="256">Thursday, August 25, 2011</option><option value="255">Wednesday, August 24, 2011</option><option value="254">Tuesday, August 23, 2011</option><option value="253">Monday, August 22, 2011</option></select></p>
```

Any ideas would be helpful.

Comment: Not related to your question at all, but: consider using cfqueryparam in your queries to protect against SQL injection attacks

Comment: What is the value of URL.day when this happens?

Comment: Output of URL.day seems to be 2011-09-5©_day=260

Comment: Please trim that code back to relevant portions only. We don't need to know what happens in the code block if it's successful. What we need is the code that builds your link(s) and, better, the HTML source of the link.

Comment: Further, this is essentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218211/date-is-not-active-issue-in-scheduler which was closed as "Not a Real Question" because it's mostly just a dump of hundreds of lines of code. You should have edited that question and request it be re-opened. In any case, please don't expect is to sift through your code to find the problem. **You** need to trim it back to show only the parts that will help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've trimmed the code and added the HTML source of the function at issue here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: As has been pointed out, the problem is not the `cfif isDate...` code. It looks like the problem is in a function called `parent.F7cms.content.iframe`, which (as Adam says) is incorrectly converting `?day=2011-09-5&copy_day=260` to either `?day=2011-09-5&copy;_day=260` or `?day=2011-09-5©_day=260` and we'd need to see that function's code to figure out what's going on.   Related question: **what is F7cms?** - if this is a third-party CMS product you're using then it seems like this is a bug in their code, and it may be worth contacting them through their support channels to get this fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment in reply to mine:

Output of URL.day seems to be 2011-09-5©_day=260

It's obvious why you're getting unexpected results (well: unexpected to *you*... the code is working fine!)... "2011-09-5©_day=260" cannot be parsed as a date, so it's failing the isDate() validation.

You need to go back to the code that calls this code, and work out why you're passing this bung data in the URL.  It looks to me like some sort of attempt to escape the ampersand in &copy_day, and it's seeing &copy as &copy;, and converting it into a copyright symbol.

Seeing the calling code might help.  But, as others say, just the RELEVANT bit!